# SQL count but exclude certain rows

Tags: mysql

I am running a query that counts submitted posts:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_author` = 4 
  AND `post_type` = 'nf_sub' 
  AND `post_status` = 'publish'
```

This returns all the posts. Now I want to exclude posts where _form_id_ = 1. This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `post_id` = 225 
  AND `meta_key` = '_form_id' 
  AND `meta_value` = 1
```

How can I combine the two into one query that only counts rows where _form_id_ is not equal to 1?

Comment: The same as you did on your first statements, just filter for `WHERE '_form_id' <> 1`

Comment: I there a related field between both tables?

Comment: What is the relation between the two tables?

Comment: The common field is ID in wp_posts and post_id in wp_postmeta

Answer (score 0):

From the tables, assuming the link field is primary key `wpposts_id` in wp_posts tables.

Use the below inner query, there are other ways to achieve this as well.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_author` = 4 
  AND `post_type` = 'nf_sub' 
  AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
  and  `wppost_id` not in ( SELECT  `wppost_id` 
                            from `wp_postmeta` 
                            WHERE `post_id` = 225 
                              AND `meta_key` = '_form_id' 
                              AND `meta_value` = 1
                          );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. Thanks to all who gave clues.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_author` = ".get_current_user_id()." AND `post_type` = 'nf_sub' AND `post_status` = 'publish' AND `ID` NOT IN ( SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_form_id' AND `meta_value` = 1)
```